# fread binary file truncates data

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread

I have a file that was created by an application on the same PC as my code. This has the following at the start:

```
$ od -c save.data
0000000  \0  \0  \0 006  \0  \0  \0      \0   D  \0   V  \0   E  \0   1
.
.
```

Using the following code in C to read the file in:

```
FILE *encfile;
char inba[8192];  // input file is < 500 bytes so this is plenty big enough

memset(inba, 0, sizeof(inba));
encfile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
int br = fread(inba, 1, 8192, encfile);
printf ("Bytes read: %d\n", br);
```

The above prints `Bytes read: 409` correctly.

The issue is that the `inba` variable is 'empty', because I think the first byte read is `0`, which gets treated as end of string. There are a number of `0` value bytes in the file.

How can I get C to see this as a 409 byte array?

The data will get passed to other functions that expect this as a  `char *` variable.

Is this an endianess issue?

Comment: It seems like your problem is in the use of the "other functions" rather than with `fread` that appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary data is generally not strings. Keep track the size by yourself.

This code will dump the contents of the array in hexadecimal:

```
// br and inba are the variable in OP's code

for (int i = 0; i < br; i++) {
    printf("%02X", (unsigned char)inba[i]);
    if (i + 1 >= br || i % 16 == 15) putchar('\n'); else putchar(' ');
}
```

Comment: The loop is good, but won't have a newline after the 409th character.  Fixing that is fiddly; you need `i` visible outside the loop so you can use `if (i % 16 != 0) putchar('\n');` after the loop — if the output must end with a newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point, but I don't think `i` should be visible outside the loop.

Comment: This answer illustrates the point well, and yes, I can see now all the data is correctly loaded into the array.

Comment: I suppose that you can use `if (br % 16 != 0) putchar('\n');` since it is a pure counting loop.